# How can I get Breeze to query $metadata instead of Metadata?

Tags: odata, breeze, jaydata

I set up my odata service with Node, MongoDB and JayData.  When I hit `http://localhost:8000/odata/findash.svc/$metadata` in my browser I get the metadata exactly as I would expect.

In the browser console I execute this sample code:

```
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('odata/findash.svc');
var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
    .from("accounts");
manager.executeQuery(query).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(e) {
    alert(e);  
});
```

An alert pops up with the message: `Error: Metadata query failed for: odata/findash.svc/Metadata; Not Found`

The net tab confirms that Breeze is hitting `odata/findash.svc/Metadata` which produces a 404 instead of `odata/findash.svc/$metadata` which works fine.

Is there a way to configure this behavior in Breeze or is the problem with my odata setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you meant OData and not JayData in your question. Breeze and JayData are two different products. If not then I'm not sure I understand the question.

I think that you haven't told breeze to use the OData endpoint.  By default breeze uses a WebApi endpoint.  You can change this via the breeze.config like this:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({
    dataService: "OData", ...
});
```

Breeze supports both OData and a WebApi endpoints.  The OData endpoint ( per the OData spec) returns metadata from '$metadata".  The webApi endpoint returns metadata from 'Metadata'.

See: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata

Comment: Thank you!  Adding that line to my sample code and including datajs solved the issue.

Comment: I am using JayData on the server and Breeze in the browser.

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have guessed that would work, but... very cool.